# Create Millisecond Loops in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, infinite-loop

Since I just found out about Excel Macros, I want to try to simulate moving objects. I would like to run some looped code every 'frame' of my project. I can make an infinite loop in Excel VBA with this code:

```
Do While True:
    'code
Loop
```

However, this crashes Excel. Is there a way to make an infinite loop that runs every ten milliseconds or so, something like this:

```
Dim timer as Timer
If timer = 10 Then
    'code
    timer = 0
End If
```

**EDIT:** Your answers are very good, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to be able to run other code at the same time; a bit like Javascript's

```
setInterval(function(){}, 200);
```

which can run multiple functions simultaneously.

Comment: You want to create an infinite loop? FYI that will "lock up" Excel and you won't be able to do anything else.  I would think even separating a loop by 10 milliseconds would eventually crash the program as well.  What's the broader purpose you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API call and Sleep.

Put this at the top of your module:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Then you can call it in a procedure like this:

```
Do While True:

Sleep 10    'wait 0.01 seconds

Loop
```

If the code is in 64bit OS, you will need to use PtrSafe. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/983043/compile-error-the-code-in-this-project-must-be-updated-for-use-on-64

Answer (score 0):

Your original method is crashing Excel because it is creating an infinite loop with no exit condition.

The second method doesn't work because your system clock time (given by `Timer`) will never be `10`, if you use `debug.Print(Timer)` in your Immediate Window you will see its value.

Here is some commented code to execute some actions based on a timer. Please please PLEASE make sure you retain the `runtime` condition for exiting the `while` loop, infinite loops are the devil and really you should have some other exit code in here somewhere!

```
Sub timeloop()
    Dim start As Double: start = Timer     ' Use Timer to get current time
    Dim t As Double: t = start             ' Set current time "t" equal to start
    Dim interval As Double: interval = 1   ' Interval for loop update (seconds)
    Dim nIntervals As Long: nIntervals = 0 ' Number of intervals passed

    ' Use this While loop to avoid an infinite duration! Only runs for "runtime" seconds
    Dim runtime As Double: runtime = 10
    Do While t < start + runtime
        ' Check if a full interval has passed
        If (t - start) / interval > nIntervals Then
            nIntervals = nIntervals + 1
            ' Do stuff here ---
            Debug.Print (t)
            ' -----------------
        End If
        t = Timer ' Update current time
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Timer does not *'get current time'*; it retrieves the number of seconds after midnight (to a millisecond decimal). Care must be taken that if you ever cross midnight during the time interval that you correct the interval limit. e.g. 23:59:55 is 86,395. Ten seconds later (00:00:05 the next day) Timer reports as 5.

Comment: So it does *get current time [since midnight]*... thanks for the clarification,  if the OP needs to tackle that case then either reset `start` and `nIntervals` when `t` goes to zero, or use [another time function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_date_time.htm)